# Text that resizes with its container

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a component with text that always completely fills its container.
i.e. if the component is small, the text should also be small and when the component is beeing resized, the text should be resized too. 
Ideally, text should be resized pixel by pixel.

Is this possible?

Comment: There was a proposal that would allow font sizes as percentages of the window width and height - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths - but I don't think that this will make it through to the final CSS3 specs.

Comment: If the container resizes as the browser window resizes, then you could use media queries to define the container and font sizes. Otherwise, if the container is resizeable independent of the browser window, you will need JavaScript.

Comment: @LucyLou: If it can be done, show how. I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure CSS, and HTML, no. Percentage font sizes refer to the font size of the enclosing container: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-prop

Instead, if using only HTML, you would have to use javascript to find the size of the container, and set the font size to that number of pixels. I leave it as an exercise to you what to do about widths.

An alternative would be to create your text as SVG, and set the SVG to completely fill your div.

Comment: Javascript does not allow to set font height and width indepentently, does it? Svg sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @Markus: Correct - that is why the correct behaviour in that case is left for you to determine.

Comment: I'll go with svg. Don't know if it allows to resize text height and width independently but at least size itself adjusts nicely. Thanks.

Comment: @Markus: It does. It also allows you to pick one axis to determine the resizing.

Comment: I just found out about the viewbox property. Awesome, that's exactly what I needed!